# How to add checkboxes to propertypane dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, spfx-custom-property-pane

I have a dropdown on my property pane which i populated with sharepoint lists.
What i want to do now is to add the columns(fields) of the list(selected on the dropdown) as checkbox(on the property pane) after i select the list in the dropdown. Any ideas on where i should start?

Best Regards,

Comment: Nothing is clear..

Comment: Update you answer and add more information and for examle some screenshot or code. It is not clear what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use [PropertyFieldListPicker](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldListPicker/). In your scenario I think the only convenient option is to go with custom property pane control implementation.

You should build a component, which allows users to select a list, then dynamically populates fields from this list as checkbox element. Wrap this component as a custom property pane. You can store settings (selected list and fields) in json format as a string property of a webpart.

Check out [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls) on how to build a custom property pane.

Comment: Is it possible to create custom control without using react?

Comment: Technically it's possible, however, it's a way more difficult than with react. What's even worse, you will not find any good tutorials (except for react of course).